# PHP - Why functions are executed when include file is called?

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to do a inactivity logout, so I have a PHP file where `logout()` is defined.
Then I have a snippet for checking the time the session is opened and stayed in same page.
But when I do `include_once "logout.php"` or `include "logout.php"` my `logout()` function is called procedurally and don't want this behaviour. How can I make a function, include it in other file and don't be executed?

logout.php:

```
<?php

  include_once "con.php";
  /*$executeLog = false;
  if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
    $executeLog=true;
  }

  if($executeLog){
    logout();
  }
    */
  function logout(){
    session_start(); 
    global $con; 
    //0-> entrada
    //1-> salida
    $q = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO logs (usuario,fecha_hora,entrada_o_salida) VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_id'].",CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),1)");
    //echo ($q) ? 'yes' : 'error :'.var_dump($q); 
    //exit();
    // Elimina la variable email en sesión.
    unset($_SESSION['email']);
    unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    unset($_SESSION['nombre_apellidos']);
    // Elimina la sesion.
    session_destroy();
    $executeLog = false;
    // Redirecciona a la página de login.
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily");
    header("Location: index.php");
  }

?>
```

snippet:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once "con.php";
include "logout.php";

$_SESSION['loginTime'] = time();

if($_SESSION['loginTime'] < time()+MAX_SESSION_TIME*60){ logout(); } 

(...)
?>
```

EDIT: Damn, was doing wrong the condition. Sorry.

Comment: Your function executed because `if` statement is `true`.

Comment: The `if` in the calling script is always true.

Comment: @u_mulder damn, was doing the condition reversed. Thanks.

Comment: you can set max session time within server configuration.For example apache has session.gc_maxlifetime to set max session time. what you are doing is always requests somethng from server so it will never be idle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The if is checking if the time they logged in is less than `time()+MAX_SESSION_TIME*60` which will always be true.

Simply checking the opposite will fix your issue:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once "con.php";
include "logout.php";

$_SESSION['loginTime'] = time();

if($_SESSION['loginTime'] > (time()+MAX_SESSION_TIME*60)){ logout(); } 

(...)
?>
```